# Using clang-format in CLion

Tags: c++, clang, clion, clang-format

I'd like to format my code using clang-format in CLion. I've gone through the settings and haven't found any setting that would allow me to run an external command to transform code. How are such things normally done in CLion?

Comment: Related CLion issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4805

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use *External Tools* in CLion.

Go to `File->Settings->Tools->External Tools` and click on the plus sign.

A window should pop up. Use a name of your choice.

For the `Tool settings` tab I'm using this configuration:

- Program: `clang-format-3.7` (you should use the name of your executable here)
- Parameters: `-i $FileName$`
- Working directory: `$FileDir$`

Now, with your file open, you can go to `Tools->External tools` and run the config above. It basically calls *clang-format* and does inplace formatting.

You can also set a custom keymap to it, just search the name of your external tool in "Keymap" of the Settings menu.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is it possible to aply it to all files? Is there any clang-format to Clion formating options guide?

Comment: @DuckQueen: clang-format uses the LLVM style by default, but it can also use others. CLion supports most, if not all, of those styles, which you can set like this: https://twitter.com/clion_ide/status/758203475704635392

Comment: I was struggling to get clang-format to run whenever you save a file. These instructions were helpful: https://marcesher.com/2014/03/30/intellij-idea-run-goimports-on-file-save/

Answer (score 13):

The lates version of **CLion 2019.1** has native support for ClangFormat.

For previous version go to `File->Preferences->Plugins` and search for `ClangFormatIJ`. Install this plugin.

It installs the context menu to invoke locally installed `clang-format` for a file or for a selection. It also set up the key shortcut for 'Reformat current Statement with clang-format' action.

This option works quite well for me in **CLion 218.3** however, it might be included in an early version as well.

Comment: ClangFormatIJ is super slow... I mean when I press shortcut for code format it takes sometimes 1-3 secs to update code... If you save file during formating it will break your code (cut some parts or other odd things). It also hangs clion when you press it multiple times... Some kind deadlock I think. [Check for issues](https://github.com/mprobst/ClangFormatIJ/issues)

Comment: Probably it depends. I never run in that problem. Good news is that everybody can looking forward for native support of clang format in next release. Here is a already planned task [CPP-4809](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4809)

Answer (score 12):

The previous answers work well, but do not allow executing clang-format on save without the use of workarounds which don't work with the Vim emulation plugin I am using.

Here is a solution which executes clang-format on save and works well in every situation that I have encountered.

- First you need to install the `File Watchers` plugin.
- From there you need to go to `File->Settings->Tools->File Watchers` And create a custom template
  [image: Creating a new file watcher in the clion settings panel]
- I use the following settings to execute `clang-format` when one of the currently open files is saved. You can tweak these settings to match your needs
  [image: My clang-format file watcher settings]

  - For example, if you wish to execute `clang-format` automatically whenever the file changes (without needing to save) you can enable `Advanced Options->Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher`

Documentation for the File Watchers plugin: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/using-file-watchers.html

Answer (score 8):

Since CLion 191 EAP ClangFormat is [supported from the box.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/tag/clangformat/)

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: For clion 2023.1 or nearly, please refers to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clangformat-as-alternative-formatter.html