# Clion code formatting to align variables

Tags: c++, c, clion

Is it possible to change the options in Clion so that the variables are aligned like so:

[image]

This should be applied in structs and methods.

Comment: Err... your variables are not aligned.

Comment: @axiac yea that's a valid point, but you get the idea, let me try and get a better image in the meantime

Comment: Oh, you're talking about source code formatting not alignment in memory layout, right?

Comment: @5gon12eder yes absolutely

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

`Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C/C++ -> Wrapping and Braces -> Variable groups -> Align in columns`

You can of course also use a custom formatting tool that does it as well.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot, I didn't see that option being packed by 100 other options.

Comment: I am sorry, is this possible to align the comments on the "right" as well ? so that the comments are aligned too ? have you seen that option ?

Comment: Not sure if that is also possible. If not, you can also use an external tool for formatting, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34648255/620382

Comment: This setting behaves weirdly if you also change the space insert from before to after in `*` declarations. Apparently the `*` is still chosen as alignment character.

Answer (score 0):

after all tuning you can also use shortcuts "Ctrl+Alt+L"
to make alignment