# Prevent Auto Format from align Pointer to variable

Tags: ide, clion, autoformatting

When i click on `Reformat Code` `Clion` changes my pointers

from:

```
int* pointer;
```

to:

```
int *pointer;
```

How can i prevent that from happening?

I searched through the settings but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You should prefer `int *pointer`, other wise `int* pointer1, pointer2;` doesn't do what you probably want.

Comment: That might be right but i never would initialize multiply variables in one line/statement.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer; They are saying, they would never create multiple pointer variables on the same line. IE: `int *ptr, *ptr2, *ptr3`.. They'd do:  `int* ptr; int *ptr2; int *ptr3;` instead.

Comment: Oh, that was a spelling error in OP's comment. My bad there.

Comment: In that case, visit https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/code-style.html . This link provides information on how to adjust code style.

Comment: You can also try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550885/clion-code-formatting-to-align-variables .

Comment: Thanks, It seems you can set the alignment of pointers in the code style settings. I may have overlooked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment of pointers can be set in the code style settings.