# CLion formatting of pointer/references

Tags: c++, formatting, clion

From reformatting, I want:

```
int* n;
int& m;
int const* o;
```

instead, I get:

```
int *n;
int &m;
int const *o;
```

How to make CLion do what I want?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Prevent Auto Format from align Pointer to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697900/prevent-auto-format-from-align-pointer-to-variable) points to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/code-style.html

After searching the many options... in Settings

```
Editor -> Code Style -> C/C++ -> Spaces ->

From:
    before '*' in declarations
    before '&' in declarations

to:
    after '*' in declarations.
    after '&' in declarations.
```

Comment: Thank you. It's dumb to have that way as default.