# How can I enable auto formatting in CLion?

Tags: coding-style, clion, jetbrains-ide, code-formatting

I installed CLion a day ago and I want to format the code automatically after I type semicolon like in Visual Studio (I am coding in C++). I tried the code style menu but it works only if I format it manually wit <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700870/5288316) might achieve what you're looking for, although you'll be using `clang-format` and not the built-in auto formatter. I'm also not sure how practical it is.

Comment: Hello Nicolas! Thanks for your comment, it helped me a lot, but it still format only when i run it and i want to format every time i write a new line of code. Have you any idea how can i do it?

Comment: I think file watchers are only triggered when you save the file. Maybe you could change the auto save delay to 1 second in the system settings? I'm aware it's not exactly the solution you needed.

Comment: If the file will be saved at 1second than wont it be laggy?